# Remove duplicate from response

Tags: go

I have the following task: I'm making loop that doing requests to server and recieving a value, for example it is a slice of ints. Then I need to pass this slice of ints to another task. The thing is that sometime I recieve duplicate value from server, for example:

```
resp1 := []int{1,2,3,4} > do some things
resp2 := []int{3,4,5,6} > do some things
```

But I want to pass only NEW values from response to next task

```
resp1 := []int{1,2,3,4} > pass 1,2,3,4
resp2 := []int{3,4,5,6} > pass 5,6
```

Is there any solution to avoid / "clean up" duplicates from value?

Answer (score 2):

The general idea would be to maintain a global <del>slice</del> map (as suggested by [mkopriva](https://stackoverflow.com/users/965900/mkopriva) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538076/remove-duplicate-from-response/73538180?noredirect=1#comment129861084_73538180)) which would memorize any value you are passing to your other task.

Build also a new slice which would:

- test for each value 'x' (of `respx`) in the global map:

  - if present, your new slice would *not* include that value
  - if absent, your new slice would include that value (and an empty struct value would be added to your global map, with 'x' as key)
- pass the new slice (with only new values, never passed before) to the new task

The point is: your current task is stateful and need to maintain a state between each call.

You will need some kind of [global variable](https://linuxhint.com/golang-global-variables) and/or [singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/go/example), something which will span the life of the execution of your program.
mkopriva also mentions the "[visited pattern](https://github.com/golang/go/search?q=visited)" as implementation examples.

Comment: that what I was thinking to do, but how can I introduce global slice in golang? I tried but it did not work.

Comment: @RipOff some kind of [global variable](https://linuxhint.com/golang-global-variables) and/or [singleton](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/go/example), something which will span the life of the execution of your program.

Comment: @RipOff note that this commonly done with maps rather than slices. I.e. you'd declare a map whose key type would be the type of those values for which you'd like to enforce uniqueness, the element type would be `bool` (or `struct{}` if you worry about space), then, before adding a new entry, you'd first check if that entry already exists or not, e.g. `if m[3] { // 3 is done` (with `bool` elements), or `if _, done := m[3]; done { // 3 is done` (with `struct{}` elements).

Comment: @mkopriva Good point, thank you for the feedback. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @RipOff use of this "pattern" can be found in the standard packages aplenty: https://github.com/golang/go/search?q=visited

Comment: thank u all for ur answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can store the values you have already seen in a map and using that you can generate unique values each time you get a response. A function to get unique response can be like this :

```
func getUniqueResponse(curResp []int, seen map[int]bool) []int {
    var resp []int
    for _, num := range curResp {
        if !seen[num] {
            seen[num] = true
            resp = append(resp, num)
        }
    }
    return resp
}
```

You can declare a `map[int]bool` and pass that map along with slice and receive a unique slice.

```
seen := make(map[int]bool)
resp := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
uniqueResp := getUniqueResponse(resp, seen)
// Do other work with unique Response
resp = []int{3, 4, 5, 6}
uniqueResp = getUniqueResponse(resp, seen)
// Do other work with unique Response
```